# Alternative to an idiom fall on deaf ears

Tags: idiom-request

Is there any alternative for the idiom **fall on deaf ears** in the context of the following sentence:

> Far from letting the matter **fall on deaf ears**, I shall give effect to the principle established by the Supreme Court on the subject under consideration

I find an article saying that the phrase sounds offensive to deaf community. I attach the link below:
[Fallingondeafearsoffensive](https://www.hearinglikeme.com/is-the-phrase-falling-on-deaf-ears-offensive/)

Comment: If the speaker is referring to their own ears, you could replace it with _ignoring the matter_.

Comment: We don't talk about letting things fall on our *own* deaf ears, though we might say we turned a blind eye to them, if it is not deemed equally offensive. For example, you could say "Far from turning a blind eye to it, I shall...".

Comment: Yes. There are many examples, most of which are not idioms. Far from *overlooking*, far from *letting the matter pass unremarked upon*, far from *ignoring*, are all examples. You may want to make the sentence less abstract, though. "Give effect to the principle..." will leave most readers wondering what it is that you're doing.